# Tengo un problema al registrar datos en la base

Tags: php, html, mysql

Soy nuevo en php y creacion de paginas web.
Tengo un formulario que permite registrarte en la pagina y otro que te ayuda a logearte, pero al intentar registrarte los datos no son almacenados en la base, no me da ningún error pero tampoco me guarda los datos del usuario.

Al intentar conectar no envía datos a la base, he intentado distintas formas, pero creo que el error se encuentra en el código de enviar, les agradecería mucho su aporte.

```
<?php
require 'database.php';
require 'insertar.php';
$mensaje = '';
$nomdb = '';
$contdb = '';
$fecdb = '';
$corrdb = '';

if (!empty($_POST['correo']) && !empty($_POST['contrasena'])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO 'user' ('id', 'nombre' , 'contrasena' , 'fecha_nacimiento','correo') VALUES (NULL, '" . $nomdb . "', '" . $contdb . "', '" . $fecdb . "', '" . $corrdb . "')";
    $listo = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $listo->bindParam(':correo', $_POST['correo']);
    $contrasena = password_hash($_POST['contrasena'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $listo->bindParam(':contrasena', $contrasena);
    if ($listo->execute()) {
        $mensaje = 'Ususario ha sido creado correctamente';
    } else {
        $mensaje = 'Ha habido un error';
    }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<link href="login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="login.js" type="text/javascript">
<link href="login.php" type="text/php">
<div class="login-wrap">
    <div class="login-html">
        <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="tab" class="entrar" checked><label for="tab-1" class="tab">Entrar</label>
        <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="tab" class="registro"><label for="tab-2" class="tab">Registrate</label>
        <div class="formulario-login">
            <div class="formulario-entrada">
                <form action="index.php" method="post" class="entras">
                    <div class="grupo">
                        <label for="userb" class="label">Nombre de Usuario</label>
                        <input id="userb" type="text" class="input" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grupo">
                        <label for="contrasenab" class="label">Contraseña</label>
                        <input id="contrasenab" type="password" class="input" data-type="password" required>
                    </div>
                    <!---
                <div class="grupo">
                    <input id="marcador"  type="checkbox" class="check" checked>
                    <label for="marcador"><span class="icon"></span> Mantenme iniciado</label>
                </div>
                -->
                    <div class="grupo">
                        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Entrar">
                    </div>
                    <div class="hr"></div>
                    <div class="linkreferencia">
                        <a href="olvidaste/olvidaste.php">Olvidaste la contraseña?</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <form action="index.php" method="post" class="registrate">
                <div class="formulario-registro">
                    <div class="grupo">
                        <label for="usuario" class="label">Nombre de usuario</label>
                        <input id="usuario" type="text" class="input" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grupo">
                        <label for="contrasena" class="label">Contraseña</label>
                        <input id="contrasena" type="password" class="input" data-type="password" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grupo">
                        <label for="contrasena1" class="label">Repetir contraseña</label>
                        <input id="contrasena1" type="password" class="input" data-type="password" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grupo">
                        <label for="edad" class="label">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
                        <input id="edad" type="date" class="input" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grupo">
                        <label for="correo" class="label">Correo Electronico</label>
                        <input id="correo" type="email" class="input" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grupo">
                        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Sign Up">
                    </div>
                    <div class="hr"></div>
                    <!--
                <div class="linkreferencia">
                    <label for="tab-1">Ya eres  usuario?</a>
                </div>
                --->
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Conexión con la base de datos:

```
<?php
$servidor = 'localhost';
$usuario = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'php_login_database';

$conn = mysqli_connect( $servidor, $usuario, "" ) or die ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");

// Selección del a base de datos a utilizar
$db = mysqli_select_db( $conexion, $database ) or die ( "Upps! Pues va a ser que no se ha podido conectar a la base de datos" );
// establecer y realizar consulta. guardamos en variable.
```

Answer (score 4):

Intenta realizar el siguiente cambio en tu código

```
<?php 
require 'database.php';
require 'insertar.php';
$mensaje = '';
$nomdb = '';
$contdb = '';
$fecdb = '';
$corrdb ='';

if (!empty($_POST['correo']) && !empty($_POST['contrasena'])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user (id, nombre, contrasena, fecha_nacimiento, correo) VALUES (NULL, '".$nomdb."', :contrasena, '".$fecdb."', :correo)";
    $listo = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $listo->bindParam(':correo', $_POST['correo']);
    $contrasena = password_hash($_POST['contrasena'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $listo->bindParam(':contrasena', $contrasena);
    if ($listo->execute()) {
        $mensaje='Ususario ha sido creado correctamente';
    }else {
        $mensaje='Ha habido un error';
    }
}
```

Primero creo que no deberías usar las comillas simples `'` en el nombre de la tabla y los campos de la misma. Adicionalmente, comprueba que los nombres sean correctos.

Si vas a escribir el valor de `$corrdb` directamente en la sentencia SQl, no puedes utilizar el método `bindParam()`. De igual forma sucede con `$contdb`.

Si nada de esto resuelve tu problema, intenta imprimir el contenido de `$conn->error`.
Este es quien te dirá si tuviste un problema, te sugiero que lo agregues en seguida del `if-else`:

```
if ($listo->execute()) {
    $mensaje='Ususario ha sido creado correctamente';
}else {
    $mensaje='Ha habido un error';
}
echo $conn->error;
```

De esta forma puedes saber si tuviste un error. No olvides quitarlo una vez termines de depurar tu código.